# Angularjs, HTML5 - How to undo a page/form which was cleared using reset operation?

Tags: angularjs, forms, undo

I am using angularJS and HTML5 in designing a web page. I am looking for means to undo a page (preferably using Ctrl+Z key combination) which was cleared using Reset button.

The reset function sets blank value ('') to all the field values in $scope.

Assume I have 10 fields in the page with values in all 10 fields. I reset the fields, now everything is blank. Now I need a means so that I undo this change. I must be able to populate all these 10 field back.

Is this achievable using angularJS? If yes, how do i implement it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The library [angular-history](https://github.com/decipherinc/angular-history) provides undo/redo.

Or see angular.copy method which can be used to store object copy.